# Calling same function on both mouse click and key press using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call the same function in javascript either on mouse click or keypress(enter).This is my code in html but it is not working..how can i do it.?

```
<div class="C" onclick="Cfunc()" onKeyDown="if(keycode==13)Cfunc();">
  <p >C</p>
</div>
```

and this is my js code:

```
function Cfunc() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("Caudio")
  audio.play();
}
```

Comment: How do you imagine a keydown on a DIV?

Comment: Keydown on an element only works on an input or text area. You can't keydown on a div because, even though you can see the div, you are not actually affecting it, just viewing it. You need to listen for the keydown on the window onject, which can be done using the     window.onkeydown = yourFunctionNameGoesHere.

Comment: @AndrewTet It's possible, if it's [focusable](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#focusable). It can be made focusable with [`tabindex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute) attribute, e.g. `tabindex="-1"`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it outside of the markup like so:

```
// elements
var audio    = document.getElementById("Caudio")
var play_btn = document.querySelector('.C')

// event handlers
play_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  audio.play()
})
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  if ( event.keyCode == 13 ) {
    audio.play()
  }
})
```

If you don't want the keydown event bound to the entire document, make the div focusable and change it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

you can do this to make this work for both

```
<div class="C" onclick="Cfunc()" onKeyDown="Cfunc();">
  <p >C</p>
</div>
```

and this is my js code:

```
function Cfunc(e) {
  if(e.keycode && e.keycode!=13)
   return;
  var audio = document.getElementById("Caudio")
  audio.play();
}
```